# Ability to link two spreadsheet in google spreadsheet using sheet api

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am using google sheets API in java  to work with google sheets. And i want to link two spreadsheet but when i link two spreadsheets using import range("","") function ,then first time its ask me to allow access other wise it raise #REF error in my sheets . How can i avoid it programmatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There unfortunately is no way right now to click the "ALLOW" portion of an importrange programatically.